# Change default directory in wix

Tags: directory, wix, guid

How do I change the default installation directory (such as D:/ or E:/) in a WiX installer where the components have auto generated guid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution. It works for me.

Add the following property inside the product tag

```
 <Property Id="ROOTDRIVE"><![CDATA[D:\]]></Property>
```

Inside your directory tag add the  'ComponentGuidGenerationSeed' attribute and give a initial guid.
Sample of the directory structure

```
<Fragment>
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
   <Directory Id="Folder1" Name="Folder1">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Folder2" ComponentGuidGenerationSeed="PUT-YOUR-GUID"/>
     </Directory>
 </Directory>
```

Comment: How to read the path from a .ini file and set the ROOTDRIVE?